# A simple way to convert a static class to regular class in legacy applications to enable mocking

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, legacy

Static classes in legacy applications are hard to use in unit tests because you cannot mock them.

What is a simple way to convert them across the whole application to regular classes that use an Interafce?

Comment: There is no "simple" way. It's a breaking change. You have to remove any references to the class members. You can use Find&replace. If you qualify static members with their class type (e.g. `SomeType.SomeMember()`) then find the "SomeType" and replace it with "this.SomeType" (it becomes `this.SomeType.SomeMember()`). Then modify the constructor and inject the interface and initialize a private property named `SomeType`. This is a cumbersome task.

Comment: The injected type can be a wrapper of the original static type or the type that declares the static members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easiest and less risky to do this in two steps.

The **first step** is repetitive and uncreative and can be assigned to a junior engineer or could even be done with a small program.

For each class, follow these steps:

1. Remove the static keyword from the desired methods and properties.
2. Add a static member called `Instance` that contains an instance of the class. Yes, we're making a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

   ```
    //Old class
    static class MyHelpers
    {
        public static string Foo(string x) {  /* Implementation */ }
    }

    //New class
    class MyHelpers
    {
        public static MyHelpers Instance { get; } = new MyHelpers();
        public string Foo(string x) { /* Implementation */ }
    }
   ```
3. In the rest of your code base, replace static calls with calls to the instance.

   ```
    //Old code
    MyHelpers.Foo("Hello world");

    //New code
    MyHelpers.Instance.Foo("Hello world");
   ```
4. Compile to make sure you didn't miss any spots
5. Test & check in source code

The **second step** is optional. We really want to get rid of those `Instance` keywords as they break IoC (and if you keep a singleton in your code base other engineers will make fun of you). This will require you

1. Add one or more interfaces
2. Arrange for the class to be injected or otherwise made available everywhere `Instance` is used.
3. Search/replace to remove ".Instance" from all the calls.

The second step requires a little more thinking and should be assigned to a more intermediate engineer. If you have large code base, you can do this over time, or just make the change tactically as you touch code.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest quick way: write a wrapper class with virtual methods in which static methods are called.

---

There are constrained and unconstrained mocking frameworks.

Former: Moq, NSubstitute, FakeItEasy allow to mock only virtual members.

Instead use unconstrained mocking frameworks. There are several of them: TypeMock, JustMock, MS Fakes, Prig, Ionad.Fody, Pose, Harmony, MethodRedirect. Unlike constrained frameworks, they allow you to substitute static methods and classes, mock private members, etc.